# Gem install rails throwing an UnknownHostError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am trying to get my rails environment working on a mac with the latest mac OS.  I have ruby installed...

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
```

When I try to start a rails server I get this message...

```
rails -s
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

So I run 'sudo gem install rails' and get ....

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
    no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/gems/thread_safe-0.3.4.gem)
```

How would I get around this error?

Comment: Had a similar error. I literally re-ran the same command and it worked. No idea why: http://i.imgur.com/MIWkQyY.jpg

Comment: They have some DNS problem you can see in their twitter https://twitter.com/rubygems_status

Comment: @Shibi: thanks I thought I was going crazy :)

Answer (score 0):

DNS issue with rubygems is now resolved so all is well, thanks  again Shibi for the status update!